# Getting blank image when viewing MRI scan images from a dataset

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, nibabel

I am trying to view MRI scan images from kits23 dataset on Google Colab, but instead I get blank images. The path is valid and I am using nibable library to view .nii images. I don't know what the issue is, so help me solve this problem.

I was expecting the original image, but instead I get a blank image.

This is the code:

```
import nibabel as nib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
path = '/content/kits23/dataset/case_00008/segmentation.nii.gz'
image_data = nib.load(path).get_fdata()
normalized_image = (image_data - image_data.min()) / (image_data.max() - image_data.min())
plt.style.use('default')
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,4, figsize=(12,12))
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.reshape(-1)):
    ax.imshow(normalized_image[:,:,1 + i], cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.show()normalized_image.shape
```

[image: code for viewing the image]

This is the output I get:

[image: output images i am getting]

Comment: Your code seems correct. The issue might be that the planes you are plotting are empty. MRIs tend to be large images where the interesting part is in the center and the rest is just zeros. In the line `ax.imshow(normalized_image[:,:,1 + i], cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=1)` try putting a number larger than one. For example, if the MRI is 240x240x155, use `normalized_image[:,:,70 + i]`. Otherwise, you could search with NumPy where are the values different from zero.